# should posix_memalign fail on wrong size?

Tags: c++, linux, posix, memory-alignment

I am using `posix_memalign` to get some memory aligned memory. The `man pages` says that

1. the size must be power of 2
2. and multiple of sizeof(void*)

I tried this call to see what happens

```
 void* ptrs;
 int ret = posix_memalign(&ptrs, getpagesize(), 13);
```

I was surprised to see that the return value is `0`.
I usually call it this way as example

```
 void* ptrs;
 int ret = posix_memalign(&ptrs, getpagesize(), 32 * sizeof(void*));
```

Do you know why is this happening?

I am using g++4.9 under LUbuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html) says

> The value of **alignment** shall be a multiple of sizeof( void *), that is also a power of two

To be clear, here is the declaration of posix_memalign

```
int posix_memalign(void **memptr, size_t alignment, size_t size);
```

You've passed a `size` that is not power of two multiple of the pointer size. But  that's okay, because the value returned by `getpagesize()` which you use as the **alignment** probably is.

I don't see any requirements for `size`, but it probably must not be negative.

Comment: Hi. You are right! I misread the man page and the constraint is only on alignment. Thanks a lot! (I guess it is Friday!)